# Java method dispatch semantics

Tags: java, methods, subclass

This is a very odd question, so please bear with me.

I'd like to know if the Java specification guarantees that an overriding method in two subclasses is resolved via identical mechanisms in each. In other words, if I have

```
public class Foo {
    public int frob() {
        return 7;
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public int frob() {
        return 8;
    }
}

public class Baz extends Foo {
    @Override
    public int frob() {
        return 9;
    }
}
```

and a method somewhere:

```
public static int quux(Bar b) {
    return b.frob();
}
```

which I know only calls `.frob()` on `b`, how safe is it to call `quux((Bar)new Baz())`?

Comment: I did try it out, and it seemed to work just fine, by the way. I'm wondering to what degree the Java specification guarantees this behaviour.

Comment: `Baz` **is not a** `Bar`, so you cannot cast a `Baz` to a `Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

`quux((Bar)new Baz())` will not even compile. (Cannot cast from Baz to Bar since `Baz` *IS-NOT* a `Bar`).

Answer (score 0):

**-** Bar `IS-A` Foo, and Baz `IS-A` Foo.

**-** But neither Bar is a Baz nor Baz is a Bar, so this casting won't work.